# Use REST or XSL to get a Table with totals

Tags: 2013, list, client-object-model, xslt, out-of-the-box

I have a list with items that contains several columns like:

- Year
- Month
- HourCategory1
- HourCategory2
- HourCategory3

Now I want to create a table that shows only totals of the hour categories:

HourCategory1 : Sum of all items 
HourCategory2 : Sum of all items 
 
HourCategory3 : Sum of all items 
Total hours        : Sum of all HourCategory1 + HourCategory2 + HourCategory3

How can I achieve this with out-of-the box functionality using existing WebParts/ Views or Javascript, JSLink XSL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with XSL using a **XsltListViewWebPart**.

Created totalColumn template

```
  <xsl:template name="totalColumn">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:param name="fieldName"/>
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$node">
        <xsl:call-template name="totalColumn">
          <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node/following-sibling::Row"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="fieldName" select="$fieldName"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + translate($node/@*[name() = $fieldName], '.', '')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Created three variables like

Then use it like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$HourCategory1"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$HourCategory2"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$HourCategory3"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$HourCategory1+ $HourCategory2+ $HourCategory3"/>
```